# jenkins running python code getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Tags: python, jenkins

Iam a naive user, try to run a Selenium python program locally using Jenkins, but was unable to do [ This might be duplicate but unable to get answers online ] so below is the code i am trying

**Under Build**

[image: Jenkins Build Environment]

**[Output]**

```
  C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Hybrid-Pytest>call ./venv/Scripts/activate.bat 
    ImportError while loading conftest 'C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Hybrid-Pytest\testCases\conftest.py'.
    conftest.py:2: in <module>
        import selenium
    E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
    Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE
```

**Update**

```
Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\jjjj
[jjjj] $ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins8556472836440444834.bat

C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\jjjj>python -m pip freeze 
asgiref==3.2.10
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs==21.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
colorama==0.4.4
Django==3.0.7
django-filter==2.4.0
iniconfig==1.1.1
packaging==21.2
pluggy==1.0.0
py==1.11.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytest==6.2.5
pytz==2020.1
soupsieve==2.3
sqlparse==0.3.1
toml==0.10.2

C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\jjjj>exit 0 
Finished: SUCCESS
```

iam able to run code locally, in pycharm it runs fine
Can somebody help me of what setting needs to do in jenkins to run the code successfully. Thanks

Comment: sounds like your Jenkins agent doesn't have the selenium package installed.

Comment: how to check that in Jenkins i mean the path?

Comment: You could perhaps make a job that runs `python -m pip freeze` and check the output?

Comment: I see you're using a virtual environment. Have you shipped a `requirements.txt` and need to install from it?

Comment: updated  the output

Comment: Yep! See how `selenium` isn't in the output of `pip freeze`? That's why you're having trouble. You'll have to install it. Usually you package a `requirements.txt` (or use one of the other kinds of package management schemes like my favorite [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/)) and when you pull it into CI you have to install those requirements with something like `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Thank you @AdamSmith got it i was able to see the Packages are not installed i was able to install and run the code

Comment: HI @AdamSmith , A query while running code from github getting again the                    C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Hybrid-Pytest>pip list 
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.                                                                                                             Any idea ?

Comment: Looks like `pip` isn't on your PATH. Is Python? `python -m pip` works.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked, how to add pip to Path and also this is giving error   C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Hybrid-Pytest>python -m pytest -v -s  "sanity" --capture sys -rP --html=Reports\reports1.html .\testCases\  --browser chrome 
ERROR: usage: __main__.py [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
__main__.py: error: unrecognized arguments: .\testCases\ --browser chrome
  inifile: None
  rootdir: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Hybrid-Pytest